# How can I use aliases in commands?

Tags: vim, filenames, alias, bashrc

I have created `aliases` in my `.bashrc` for various frequently used long paths but I can not seem to be able to use them inside `vim` or with commands such as `find` or `grep`.
E.g the following:
`db`
in cli does `cd /some/very/long/path/db`
But in vim this:
`:e db/file.java`
or on the command line: `grep -r string db` do not work.
How is this fixed?

Answer (score 5):

You can set an environmental variable for that directory.

```
# Making the variable name consist entirely of capital letters makes the
# variable less likely to conflict with other variables in scripts. You can
# make the variable name consist of lowercase letters but you may run
# into problems. 
export DB=/some/very/long/path/db
```

Then you can use the exported variable in Vim as such:

```
:e $DB/file.java
```

and in your shell as such:

```
grep -r string $DB
```

The variable-substitution facilities of Vim and bash are entirely independent from each other. Vim just happens to substitute environmental variables in a manner similar to bash (and many other shells).

Answer (score 2):

Aliases let you give a short name to a command and some arguments. They are only expanded where a command is expected. You can't use them to abbreviate the path to a file.

Furthermore `.bashrc` is only read by interactive shells, so nothing that you define there will be available in a command typed in Vim.

If you want to have a shortcut to a file or directory, create a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to it.

```
ln -s /some/very/long/path/db ~/db
grep -r string ~/db
vim ~/db/file.java
```

You can define environment variables to abbreviate any string. Environment variable definitions go into `~/.profile`. Not every program expands them, but Vim does when you open a file with `:e` (among other things).

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to alisases for `.bashrc` you'd be surprised what you can do. I'll give few examples of what I know works because I tried them.

- `alias Documents='/home/username/Documents'` will work, but not on its own. If you pair it with, say, `alias Open='cd'`, do `source .bashrc`, and then type `Open Documents`, it will act as if you typed `cd /home/username/Documents`.
- Also, you can go this way: `alias Documents='cd home/username/Documents'`, then `source .bashrc`, then type `Documents`; it will do same as `Open Documents`, meaning `cd home/username/Documents`.

As I said, you can do a lot with aliases. When it comes to `.bashrc`, all you need to do is use you imagination and try what you came up with to see if it works.

I will look into `vim` and get back to you.

Comment: The formatting in this answer is very confusing. Can you highlight what the actual commands are using backtics? In what program is `Open Documents` a valid command even after defining `Documents` as a bash alias? The OP was asking about importing alias into `vim` and I don't see how your answer addresses this.

Comment: Open Documents isn't valid command. It's two aliases used in conjuction to represent cd home/username/Documents. Open is an alias for command cd while Documents is an alias for /home/username/Documents or as mentioned earlier an abreviated path. If there is a way to import aliases in vim than it's beyond me. Also i will highlight some parts of previous comment. You can represent entire command cd home/username/Documents with an alias Documents how ever it can be one or another. What i mentioned goes only for bash. Commands and aliases are highlighted in bold.

Comment: You cannot use multiple aliases on the same command line. If both `Open` and `Documents` are aliases and you give the command `Open Documents` only `Open` will be treated as an alias and it will try to cd to the directory `Documents`. For your second example, you probably want a leading `/` on the directory name. Otherwise the command will look for the subdirectory `home/username/Documents` under the current working directory.

Comment: @doneal24+ for bash (and ksh and zsh), the first word in a command here `Open` is checked for alias (unless quoted) and _if_ its expansion ends with a (otherwise unnecessary) space, which the posted answer does not, then the next word here 'Documents' is _also_ checked. zsh additionally supports 'global' aliases that work in any word regardless of the preceding word(s). But no kind of alias works in vim; per the much older answer an environment variable does work there _and_ in any shell, making it a more general solution.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 OK, I learned something new today. I did not know about the behavior when you have a trailing space.